# Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows

Tags: c#, silverlight, build, silverlight-5.0, .net-assembly

I am trying to build a test project for silverlight application. When i build this project it throws following error

```
Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

I have system.winwos dll in my references and i am using visual studio 2012.

What should i do to resolve this error

More Details:

If I remove system.windows.control.Navigation dll, this error no longer comes up but build requires system.windows.control.Navigation.

Comment: have you tried to check the version of your system.winwos dll in references? it's 5.0.5.0?

Comment: Maybe you have declaration in your manifest/config, try removing the one that refer to that version.

Comment: @ChrisShao System.windows version is 4.0 and path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.dll"
which is latest .Net Framework on my machine. Do you know where can i get System.Windows Version 5.0.5.0?

Comment: I created a Silverlight 5.0 project. and it contains that dll of 5.0.5.0 default. you can try to change to profile of the project. change the target framework of .Net.

Comment: @ChrisShao target framework is .net 4.5, what is target framework of your project?

Comment: @ChrisShao can you tell me the physical path of system.windows.dll version 5.0.5.0 from you project references?

Comment: You've created wrong project. Just create a New SL5 project and it should be fine. SL projects do not present the option of .net 4.5. If all else fails, reinstall SL developer tools.

Comment: @Maverik i have created a silverlight 5 project. but i will try your suggestion of reinstalling SL developer tools. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a system.windows version 5.0.5.0 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.20913.0 folder

Had to add this file manually in project.csproj file using  tag
Getting other build errors not but at least the this one is resolved.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Generally when I've had this problem it's because my application is set to build 64-bit rather than AnyCpu and the offending assembly is 32-bit. Or vice versa.

Comment: I have tried to build with both 32-bit and AnyCpu settings but getting same error everytime