# SignalR: getting error after installing SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, signalr

I have a Silverlight project. everything works, But after Installing SignalR, I'm getting this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I also included System.Windows assembly to my project and set its copy to local to True. But still have that problem. Here is the dependency in my Web.Config file:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Windows.Controls" publicKeyToken="5803cfa389c90ce7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2013.1.220.1050" newVersion="2013.1.220.1050" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.8.0" newVersion="2.6.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.8.0" newVersion="2.6.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have tested that. doesn't work.

Comment: one of solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690938/unknown-build-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your version of system.windows is indeed 5.0.5.0 like it's looking for. If yours is newer you may need to add a binding redirect in web.config like the others there.